# Slide Toggle doesnt works some time

Tags: jquery

Can any one tell me why this piece of code doesn't work some time..
sliding doesn't takes place every time, sometime it stays still after clicking...
it works well in my 21" pc screen but in my mini laptop sometimes it doesn't get triggered.

I also tried putting the script into `document.ready` function but then it doesnt work at all...

```
<div id="aboutus" onclick="showLayer('aboutus-sub');">
                <img src="more.png" id="more" title="more here.." style="width:25px;height:25px;"/></div>
    <div id="aboutus-sub" style="display:none;">
    <ul><li><a href="chatroom.php">Chat Room</a></li>
    <ul><li><a href="album.php">Album</a></li>
    <ul><li><a href="studentsarea.php">Settings</a></li>
    <ul><li><a href="studentsarea.php">i student</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
        function showLayer (){
        $('#aboutus-sub').css('visibility','visible').slideToggle('slow','swing');
    }
    </script>
```

css part is

```
#aboutus-sub{z-index:+1;
text-align:center;
border-radius:4px;
border:1px solid black;
position:absolute;
visibility:hidden;
right:15px;
top:61px;
width:100px;
color:white;
height:150px;
background-color:#042D18;
opacity:0.88;
}
li a:hover{
color:#FFFF24;
text-decoration:underline;
}
ul{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
li{
list-style:none;
padding:2px 0px;
border-bottom:1px dashed #060DD6;
margin-bottom:5px;
}
li a{
font-weight:bold;
margin-bottom:6px;
display:block;
color:white;
text-decoration:none;
}
.last{
border:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the `.css('visibility','visible')`, e.g.

```
$('#aboutus-sub').slideToggle('slow','swing');
```

slideToggle will take care of the visibility for you :)

Comment: hmm.. also maybe try moving `style="display:none;"` out into the head, because inline styling can cause problems sometimes..

Comment: Remove `visibility: hidden` from `#about-us` in your stylesheet.  You should also clean up HTML (stray table tags), move the click handler into your script, and run on document load.  See http://jsfiddle.net/gJBTQ/3/. I didn't load `slideToggle` so I changed it to `toggle()` to demonstrate.